# Get File and download from rest api

Tags: javascript

On click on download button I need to "GET" an xml file from rest api url (http://localhost:xxxx/xx.xml) and save it on users desktop. How do I achieve this in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I would open that URL in a new tab and let the user handle it. That's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have control over the webhost, send the header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=x.xml
```

You could also use AJAX call and something like the [downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) flash object. Other than these there is no native way to force the downloading of a file

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your_button').click(function(){
    window.open('http://localhost:xxxx/xx.xml');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to download the file as well. Any idea on how to implement download.